# Matlab doesn't wait for user input after pressing enter on previous figure

Tags: matlab, input, enter

So I have this bit of code which used to work in previous versions of Matlab but now in the R2015a version it doesn't work anymore.

This code allows a user to click on a picture to get the pixel coordinates of a desired amount of points and then through user input function, the user can give the world coordinates of those points as they are circled on a figure.

The thing is that it seems like as I press "Enter" to confirm the last point on the phase, it stays on the buffer and when the input section comes up, matlab thinks I pressed enter without having the time to give the coordinates.

I tried using `set(gcf,'CurrentCharacter','char(0))` to fix this issue but it doesn't work.

If I use the "debug" mode, and I stop at the input line : it works.

```
npoints = input('How many points do you want to select in the picture ? ') ;
refpoints = cell(1,npoints);

for i = 1:npoints % this bit of code allows the user to zoom on a figure, press escape 
% when he's done zooming, click on the desired point and then press enter to confirm
   fig = figure ;
   imshow(picture)
   zoom on;   
   waitfor(gcf,'CurrentCharacter',char(27));
   zoom off
   refpoints{i} = ginput(1); % select point round to the closest pixel
   waitfor(gcf,'CurrentCharacter',char(13));
   close(fig);
end

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Cell2array... %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

x1 = zeros(npoints,1); % pixel coordinates
y1 = zeros(npoints,1);

for k = 1:size(refpoints,2)
x1(k) = round(refpoints{1,k}(1));
y1(k) = round(refpoints{1,k}(2));
end

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Calculating the world coordinates %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

disp('Now you need to give the physical coordinates to each of the points specified!')
disp('-----------------------')

world = zeros(npoints,2);
X1 = zeros(npoints,1); % Real world coordinates
Y1 = zeros(npoints,1);

fig1 = figure ;
for jj=1:npoints
imshow(picture);
hold on
plot(x1(jj),y1(jj),'wo');
hold off
world(jj,:) = input('Please enter the world coordinates for the white \n circle  marked in the current figure (in square parenthesis): ');
end
close(fig1);
```

Do you have any idea on how to fix this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I used Space Bar instead of Enter and it works fine.